# The meaning of "Так-то оно так, раз для себя"

Tags: значения

> **[Так-то оно так](http://flibusta.site/b/404471/read)**, **раз** **для себя**. Но все же тут пореже бы чуток, чтобы узор видней был. Вот для сравненья мою сейчас посмотришь.
>
> [also]: **Так-то оно так, раз оно не эдак**.

The word "раз", as well as the phrase "так-то оно так", has me puzzled.

Is this a different expression from "**так-то оно так**, **а**/**но**/**да** ..."?

Comment: Give more context, please.

Comment: usually it would mean IF, but to be able to translate the phrase context is needed... так-то оно так sounds peculiar here, seems to have been used not entirely according to its meaning, because of being followed by IF, which isn't a contradiction to be expected

Answer (score 1):

„раз“ here just has the meaning of „if“.

- Так-то оно так, раз для себя — it is so, if it is for yourself/ourselves;
- Так-то оно так, раз оно не эдак — it is so, unless it's the other way („it is this, if it is not that“ maybe).

Answer (score 1):

Так-то оно так: `I can understand it / agree with that / accept it.`
Раз для себя: `If it is for my(our) good.`

Так-то оно так, раз оно не эдак: `This, perhaps, should be so, if in another way - not right(there is no other way / does not exist).`

Answer (score 0):

> Так-то оно так, раз для себя. Но все же тут пореже бы чуток

This is very vernacular as are the dialogues in the text in general. The logical sequence of clauses should be

> Так-то оно так, но все же тут пореже бы чуток

**Так-то оно так** here is agreement with a phenomenon (of a dense crochet-work) and not with someone's explicit statement. Basically with an imaginary statement.

> Так-то оно так, раз для себя. Но все же тут пореже бы чуток

Can be unpacked as **`Well if it's for your own use, i guess it's OK. But still would benefit from a bit sparser knitting`**